# Functions in my powershell profile don't show up?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script and the default `ExecutionPolicy` for the machine is set to `AllSigned`.

To get around this for just the powershell window I'm using I use:

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

There isn't much in my profile at the moment, but as new tasks arise, I want to be able to add functions to it like so:

```
## Auth stuff
#Import-Module $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\storecredz.psm1

# NOTE: This sets the ExecutionPolicy to Bypass for the current powershell window...
#       `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`


    function initAssets($blah) {

        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Assets - New Beta"
        Import-Module $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\psm\assets\init.psm1
    }
```

Currently above is what I have in my powershell profile...and since it isn't signed (none of it is :\ yet) after I set the `ExecutionPolicy` for the PS Window, I run `.\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` and I was expecting that it would then load my `initAssets` function...but it does not.

When I copy and paste it from the profile into the window of course it works...but I was sort of hoping to just be able to run the function when I start the task of looking at the assets...

Is there any particular reason why it might not pull that up when I press tab to complete the function?  The profile runs with no errors...and I've event tried it in a fresh Powershell window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [Dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6)

> Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and
>   variables that the script creates are added to the current scope.

Use as follows:

```
. .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Another hint: set default execution policy to `RemoteSigned` rather than `AllSigned`.